# FP 11 broke my flex app in Chrome when its run as file:///

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash

I have a flex/AS3 application that has worked flawlessly run either in the local file system (file:///C:...html), or accessed through a localhost server, or accessed through a remote server.  It works whether compiled under flex 3 or flex 4.

That is, it all worked on FP 10 and before.  However, I just discovered it is broken under FP 11 (but only on Chrome) in that it will only run when accessed from a web server now (either locally or remote), and will not run in the local file system. (Still runs on FF).

If I compile under Flex 3, I can get it to run on FP 11 in Chrome by just not making  any ExternalInterface.calls to the wrapper, if its detected the swf was loaded via file:///.  However,  if compiled under Flex 4 it doesn't execute at all in Chrome if loaded via file:/// (can't even step into it apparently).  How can I resolve this.

And the reason I'm posting this here, is that I'm finding nothing on google pertaining to this change in FP 11 apparently effecting Chrome only.  To repeat, everything worked under FP 10 and before.

Comment: A security sandbox issue? You can allow the `file:///` protocol in the global settings of FP. There are answers on StackOverflow and elsewhere for how to do that

Comment: But why does this just materialize under FP 11 and only in Chrome.  That's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just got it to work with FP 11.4 r402 (the most current version).  What I had installed previously was FP 11.3.31.232, and that is the one that didn't work.  So evidently this is a very current issue here, just happened to stumble into it.  Would have tried a different flash player previously, except if you go to the flash download page, it says since you are using Chrome, its already built in.  So just now had to find out how to disable it in Chrome plugins so I could install the most current.  Don't know what the date is on that faulty version FP 11.3.31.232, but will report back if I find it.

Comment: Just to clarify, no changes in my code necessary.  the FP installed in Chrome, 11.3.31.232 would not run my flex app that was running previously.  I disabled FP in Chrome Plug-ins, downloaded the most current from Flash - 11.4.402.265, and everything is back to normal. (This most current version is now installed in Chrome.)

Comment: Just as an update on this, the problem actually is with CHrome's new built in flash player, not the particular version number.  They have instituted some sort of "security" not present on any other Flash Player plug in.  But the crux of it is, my app fails in ambiguous ways when run as file:/// with Chrome's new "built-in" flash player.  I have to disable it and install the actual adobe flash player for my app to work in Chrome now when run locally.  Users of course won't new anything about this.  How is it that no one else has encountered this yet.  I had no problems with Chrome in the past.